# What is Sapi Server in windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, sapi

I am developing Windows Phone 7 application. Today i noticed in my console windows 'Sapi Server is now running...'. I don't know what is the use of this server.

[image]. Please let me know what is this 'Sapi server' and use of this 'Sapi Server' in windows phone 7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sapi is the Speech API.  It provides voice synthesis and speech recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAPI Server starts up whenever you use speech on Windows Phone, either via [Voice Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206959(v=vs.105).aspx), [Text To Speech](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207057(v=vs.105).aspx), or direct [Speech Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207021(v=vs.105).aspx).  (Yes, the links are to Windows Phone 8, but it's still true.)

Comment: Oh.. Thank you @Eric.. But in my app i did not use voice commands or text to speech. So it is a default ah? (Sorry for late Reply)

Comment: Did *something* on your phone use voice commands/tts?  The output is global, and Sapi Server will start up when *any* app on the phone uses the required features.